# Update page using repeater in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used repeater for bind data from database.I used pager method for listing data .When page is start to work firstly no matter. I can go to next page but other page I cant see it. When refresh page I can see page and next other one. For example ,firs page is 1 ,second page is 2,third page is 3 ,and fouth page is 4 .When Page 1 is workin I can only see next one page .if I have see 1 I can see 3 or 4 or 2.But only one .
I want to show all page orderly.
How can I solve this.
Here is my code:

```
 magazaBUS = new MagazaBUS();
            try
            {
                int magazacount = 0;
                if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "")
                {
                   magazacount = magazaBUS.MagazaCountGrp(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                }
                else
                {
                   magazacount = magazaBUS.MagazaCount();
                }
                LblToplamData.Text = " " + magazacount.ToString() + "Kayıt";
                if (magazacount > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        TotalPage = Math.Ceiling(double.Parse(magazacount.ToString()) / Varibles.CurrentDataDetay);
                        TotalBar = Math.Ceiling(double.Parse(TotalPage.ToString()) / CurrentBar);
                        DataTable dtTotalPage = new DataTable();
                        dtTotalPage.Columns.Add("PageNumber", typeof(string));
                        if (TotalBar >= PageBar)
                        {
                            if (PageBar == TotalBar)
                            {
                                for (int i = ((PageBar - 1) * CurrentBar) + 1; i <= ((PageBar - 1) * CurrentBar) + (TotalPage % CurrentBar); i++)
                                {
                                    dtTotalPage.Rows.Add(i.ToString());
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                for (int i = ((PageBar - 1) * CurrentBar) + 1; i <= (PageBar * CurrentBar); i++)
                                {
                                    dtTotalPage.Rows.Add(i.ToString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        rptPages.DataSource = dtTotalPage;
                        rptPages.DataBind();
                        if (dtTotalPage.Rows.Count >= 1)
                            pager.Visible = true;
                        else pager.Visible = false;
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }

                }
                    int baslangic = (PageNumber * Varibles.CurrentDataDetay) + 1;
                    int bitis = (PageNumber * Varibles.CurrentDataDetay) + Varibles.CurrentDataDetay;         

                if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "")
                {
                    baslangic = (PageNumber * Varibles.CurrentDataDetay) + 1;
                    bitis = (PageNumber * Varibles.CurrentDataDetay) + Varibles.CurrentDataDetay; 
                    List<MagazaVO> main = magazaBUS.MagazaListeGrp(baslangic - 1, bitis,DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                    RptList.DataSource = main;
                    RptList.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    baslangic = (PageNumber * Varibles.CurrentDataDetay) + 1;
                    bitis = (PageNumber * Varibles.CurrentDataDetay) + Varibles.CurrentDataDetay; 

                    List<MagazaVO> main = magazaBUS.MagazaListe(baslangic - 1, bitis);
                    RptList.DataSource = main;
                    RptList.DataBind();
                }

            }
            catch
            {
            }
```